# SDL Web 8.5 Solr Integration

Tags: web8.5, solr

we are planning to integrate Solr with SDL Tridion 8.5 using Razor and Dreamweaver Template. Please let us know if you have any reference of Deployer config with the required lib files or documentation to help us in integrate the Solr with SDL web 8.5, or do we need to reach out to Tridion support for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far great answers already for SI4T Solr integrations references.

I understand based on your comments, you are looking for specific 8.5 Solr jars files for your deployer-combined service.

1. Download [SI4T source](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/tree/develop/storage-extensions) Extract the source and modify **pom.xml** for Tridion version 8.5 and build against 8.5 dependencies and copy all the dependencies and **si4t-se-1.2.jar** files to SDL Deployer service installed.
2. Download [Solr source](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr) Extract the source and modify **pom.xml** for Tridion version 8.5 and build against 8.5 dependencies and above build **si4t-se-1.2.jar** and copy all the dependencies and **si4t-solr-1.2.jar** files to SDL Deployer service installed
3. Rest of the configs setup is similar.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

When you say that you're planning to integrate Solr with Tridion, presumably you mean that you want to use the Solr functionality on your published website(s)?

If that's correct, then that is quite a common requirement and you should take a look at the SI4T (Search Integration 4 Tridion) project, where most of the hard work has already been done for you.

There are two main parts to SI4T:

1. The TBBs that add the indexing directives (i.e. details of what should get indexed) to the published content, and
2. A Deployer Storage Extension that extracts this additional information from the published output and builds up the indexing actions for all items in the publish transaction.

You can take a look at the [SI4T project website](http://si4t.github.io/SI4T/) and [SI4T project wiki](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/wiki) for more details.

Comment: ha, you beat me by 35 seconds :D

Comment: Haha. Well hopefully it adds some weight to the SI4T argument! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an implementation question, reaching out to Customer Support won't help you much.

You might want to take a look at http://si4t.github.io/ which contains a nice framework for integrating Tridion with Search engines and a ready-made Solr indexer that you can use.

For Razor and Dreamweaver Templating you might need to make some changes, SI4T was focused on MVC type web applications like DD4T and DXA, although the CM side part of it is probably reusable (maybe with a few minor changes).

Comment: Guys thank you so much for the response , I just wanted to add one thing , I have done solr integration with SDL 8.1.1 with razor and dreamweaver templates before. I had some issue with publishing and had to update the lib files to fix the issue . I have SDL 8.5 deployer service running and which contains the lib  files of 8.5 , let me know which lib files need to be update for the publishing to work or does tridion 8.5 contains all required lib files by default.